# finding most frequent element in BST

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

i have a BST and each node contain a word and a frequencies.
the BST sorted according to the word.

before inserting into the BST we must check if the word in BST or not, if it is not insert it.
if it is there i will increase the frequencies by 1.

the question is

**how to get the word which have the highest frequencies?**

here is my BST class

```
public class BST {

    private BSTword root;//root as reference variable

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public BST() {
        root = null;
    }
```

and this is the node which contain the word and its frequencies

```
public class BSTword {

    private int freq;       
    private String word;    
    private BSTword left;   
    private BSTword right;  

    public BSTword() {
        word = "";
        left = right = null;
    }

    public BSTword(String word) {
        this.word = word;
        freq=1;
        left = right = null;
    }
```

and here is what i have done so far

this method in BST class

```
private BSTword mostCommonWord(BSTword p, int c) {
    if (p == null) {//No Subtree
        return p;
    } else {
        if (p != null) {
            if (p.getData() == c) {
                return p;
            }
            mostCommonWord(p.getLeft(), c);

            if (p.getLeft().getData() > c) {
                return p;
            }
            if (p.getRight().getData() > c) {
                mostCommonWord(p.getRight(), c);
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Is the BSt sorted by frequency or by the natural oder of the strings?

Comment: What does your "*BST sorted **according to the word**" actually mean? Alphabetically?

Comment: the BST is stored Alphabetically

Comment: This is not a bad question. I would consider adding some code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @JohnMercier
i have no clue how to solve this problem, so i just asked the question.
i thought traversing throw the entire BST will get the result but didn't know how to start

Comment: @AbdulmalekAhmedJey traversing the BST makes sense to me but we don't know what the BST code looks like to help. If it is in an array it may be easier to loop through it.